# substitution cipher: can't acknowledge nonrepeating characters

Tags: c, cs50

I'm having a problem with CS50's substitution cipher problem. I'm stuck on how to validate the key. Whenever I pass a 26 character key as a command-line argument, the program outputs "you must not repeat any characters" even when the key doesn't have any. My program correctly checks for the length of the key and the presence of a command-line argument. It just doesn't acknowledge a valid nonrepeating key.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool validateKey(char key[]);
string substitute(char key[], string plaintext);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
   if(strlen(argv[1]) == 26) { //key typed after prgm name will be used to encrypt data
       if(validateKey(argv[1])) {
            
            string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
            string ciphertext = substitute(argv[1], plaintext);
            printf("Ciphertext: %s", ciphertext);
            
       }
   }
   else if(argv[1] == NULL) {
       printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
   }
   else {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
   }
}

bool validateKey(char key[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if(!isalpha(key[i])) {
            printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
        an array of counters to keep track of how many times a letter occurs in the cipher
        each counter should be set to 1 if key doesn't have repeating letters
    */
    int cntr[26] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        key[i] = islower(key[i]); //make all the letters in the key lowercase to make it easier to work with
        switch(key[i]) {
            case 'a':
                cntr[0] += 1;
            case 'b':
                cntr[1] += 1;
            case 'c':
                cntr[2] += 1;
            case 'd':
                cntr[3] += 1;
            case 'e':
                cntr[4] += 1;
            case 'f':
                cntr[5] += 1;
            case 'g':
                cntr[6] += 1;
            case 'h':
                cntr[7] += 1;
            case 'i':
                cntr[8] += 1;
            case 'j':
                cntr[9] += 1;
            case 'k':
                cntr[10] += 1;
            case 'l':
                cntr[11] += 1;
            case 'm':
                cntr[12] += 1;
            case 'n':
                cntr[13] += 1;
            case 'o':
                cntr[14] += 1;
            case 'p':
                cntr[15] += 1;
            case 'q':
                cntr[16] += 1;
            case 'r':
                cntr[17] += 1;
            case 's':
                cntr[18] += 1;
            case 't':
                cntr[19] += 1;
            case 'u':
                cntr[20] += 1;
            case 'v':
                cntr[21] += 1;
            case 'w':
                cntr[22] += 1;
            case 'x':
                cntr[23] += 1;
            case 'y':
                cntr[24] += 1;
            case 'z':
                cntr[25] += 1;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if(cntr[i] != 1) {
            printf("Key must not contain repeated characters.\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

string substitute(char key[]) {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Add `break` to each `case`.

Comment: A more compact way is to replace the whole `switch` block with one line: `cntr[key[i] - 'a'] += 1;`.

Comment: The entire `switch` statement could be replaced by just `cntr[key[i] - 'a'] += 1`.

Comment: `key[i] = islower(key[i]);` -> `key[i] = tolower(key[i]);`. You might want to do something like `char k = tolower(key[i]);` and `switch(k)` to avoid modifying the original key.

Comment: @kaylum *sarcasm on* There was a race condition between our comments.

Comment: The array initialization can also be more compact: `int cntr[26] = { 0 };`. This initializes all elements of the array `cntr` to `0`; this way is less error-prone.

Comment: @LucaPolito A more more compact way is `int cntr[26] = {};` as the C standard says any remaining elements not provided by the initializer are automatically 0 :-)

Comment: @kaylum: Last I checked, you had to provide at least one value in the initializer in C (C++ allows you to omit it). MSVC doesn't require it IIRC (it allows a lot of C++-isms in C), but it's non-standard. At least according to [cppreference's page on C array initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization), it needs at least one expression, so I *think* I'm remembering the rules correctly.

Comment: You should check to be sure `argc > 1` before passing `argv[1]` to `strlen`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're probably right. I was just being silly anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The "minimal" fix is to add a `break` after each increment, so your `case 'a'` doesn't execute the code for `case 'b'` and onwards. You'd also need to change the `islower` call to `tolower` (otherwise all your key values just become `0` and `1`).

That said, the `switch` statement itself is already ridiculously overlong, and should really just be simplified to the one-liner:

```
cntr[tolower(key[i]) - 'a'] += 1;
```

which is safe, since you've already checked all the input characters pass `isalpha`.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem using your suggestion. However, my program creates an error whenever I don't provide a key. I want it to provide a return code of 1 instead of "segmentation fault."

Comment: @Programmer: That's because you access `argv[1]` (in your `strlen`, first line of `main`) without verifying if `argc` is at least 2. You need to check the argument exists at all before trying to access it.